# Java Collections of Interfaces

Tags: java, collections

I'm writing a small API to deal with objects that have specific 'traits' In this case, they all have an interval of time and a couple of other bits of data, So I write an interface TimeInterval with some getters and setters.

Now most of these API methods deal with a Set or List of Objects. Internally these methods use the Java Colletions Framework (HashMap/TreeMap in particular). So these API methods are like:

`getSomeDataAboutIntervals(List<TimeInterval> intervalObjects);`

Couple of Questions:

a) Should this be `List<? extends TimeInterval> intervalObjects` instead?

Is it mostly a matter of style? The one disadvantage of taking strictly an interface that I can see is, you need to create your list as a `List<TimeInterval>` rather than `List<ObjectThatImplementsTimeInterval>`. 
This means potentially having to copy a `List<Object..>` to `List<TimeInterval>` to pass it to the API.

Are there other pros & cons to either approach?

b) And, one dumb question :) The collections framework guarantees I always get out the same instance I put in, the collections are really a collection of references, correct?

Comment: I added code blocks for you in the post. Please look at the documentation and learn how to do it yourself for the next time.

Comment: Thanks, you got there before I edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes.

Method parameters should be as general as possible. `List<? extends A>` is more general than `List<A>`, and can be used when you don't need to add things to the list.
If you were only adding to the list (and not reading from it), the most general signature would probably be `List<? super A>`

Conversely, method return types should be as specific as possible. You rarely to never want to return a wildcard generic from a method.

Sometimes this can lead to generic signatures:

```
<T extends MyObject> List<T> filterMyObjects(List<T>)
```

This signature is both as specific and as general as possible

2) Yes, except possibly in some rare very specific cases (I'm thinking of `BitSet`, although that isn't technically a `Collection`).

Comment: It's not more general; it's more restrictive.  If you have `Interface A` with classes `B`, `C`, and `D` that implement `A`, in `List<A>` you can store instances of `B`, `C`, or `D` together in the same list.  With `List<C>`, for example, you can only store instances of `C` and not `B` or `D`.  It doesn't make any sense to create a method `getSomeDataAboutIntervals(List<? extends TimeInterval>)` - unless he's going to use `instanceOf` throughout the method he's still limited to using the `TimeInterval` interface, and then only on lists containing a single subtype of `TimeInterval`.

Comment: @Paul It is more general from the perspective of the caller of the method. They can give it a `List<A>` or `List<B>` or `List<C>`. If the method took a `List<A>` and they had a `List<C>`, they would have to preform contortions to make them work together.

I don't understand your point about `instanceof`. If `TimeInterval` doesn't expose the functionality you need within the method, it shouldn't be the wildcard bound.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your list as `List<? extends A>`, then you can pass in any object which static type is `List<X>`, where `X extends A` if `A` is a class, or `X implements A` id `A` is an interface. But you'll not be able to pass in a `List` or a `List<Object>` to it (unless `A` is `Object`) without force-casting it.

However, if you declare the parameter as a `List<A>`, you'll only be able to pass lists which static type is strictly equivalent to `List<A>`, so not `List<X>` for instance. And by "you are not able to do otherwise", I really mean "unless you force the compiler to shut up and accept it", which I believe one should not do unless dealing with legacy code.

Collections are really collections of references. The abstraction actually is that everything you can put in a variable is a reference to something, unless that variable is of a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would recommend ? extends TimeInterval.  Because of Java's polymorphism, it may not actually make a difference, but it is more robust and better style

2) Yes

Answer (score 0):

a) No.  `List<? extends TimeInterval>` will only accept interfaces that extend the interface TimeInterval.  Your assertion that "you need to create your list as a `List<TimeInterval>` is wrong, unless I misunderstand your point.  Here's an example:

```
List<List> mylist=  new ArrayList<List>();
mylist.add(new ArrayList());
```

b) Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> Should this be List intervalObjects instead?

You only do that if you want to pass in a `List<TimeIntervalSubclass>`.  Note you can put instances of subclasses of `TimeInterval` into a `List<TimeInterval>`.  Keep in mind that the type *of the list* is different than the types *in the list*.

If you do `List<? extends A> myList` -- that only affects what you can assign to `myList`, which is different than what is *in* `myList`.

> And, one dumb question :) The collections framework guarantees I
>   always get out the same instance I put in, the collections are really
>   a collection of references, correct?

When you create a collection `Map myMap = new HashMap()`,  `myMap` is a reference to the underlying collection.  Similarly, when you put something into a collection, you are putting the reference to the underlying object into the collection.